# google web engine SDK as a local web server?

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk

I'm thinking of building a dynamic web site using Google web engine Technology, however I would like to use it in a local network without internet . Can I use the Google web engine SDK as a LOCAL SERVER.In other words, is the SDK just for development and testing purposes or it can be used as a server?

Should I worry about long-term use of SDK as a local web server, is there any scalability issues I should be aware of.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run Google App Engine Development Server on my own server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881672/is-it-possible-to-run-google-app-engine-development-server-on-my-own-server)

Answer (score 0):

You probably could, but there'd be no point.

GAE makes all sorts of tradeoffs which only make sense in terms of the benefits you get by running on Google's infrastructure: for example, the limited querying you can do with the datastore, or the strict timeout on requests.

Plus, the development server is extremely limited in what it can serve, so you'd need to put a proper web server in front of it anyway.

If you're using Python, you can use webapp2 as a standalone WSGI application, although you might be better off going directly for something like Django. I don't know much about serving Java apps directly but I guess you can use Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I wanted to use python for the development that's what led me to GAE, I'll read more about the Django framework

Thank you again.